# MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mlab

So I'm working my way though the Getting Mean book from Manning and following the steps in Chapter 5 I'm trying to use a db on Mongolab as an add-on to Heroku. When I run this code (both locally and on Heroku) it returns this error:

> MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017

This is my current code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var dbURI = "mongodb://localhost/loc8r";
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    dbURI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
}
mongoose.connect(dbURI);
```

Troubleshooting I started the app from the terminal with:

```
NODE_ENV=production MONGOLAB_URI=/*my mongo uri here*/
```

with that it runs fine locally. So I'm not sure where the issue is coming from. Any suggestions for troubleshooting the error listed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not sure what part of this process fixed the issue but I completely removed/deleted the mongolab addon from Heroku. Then I added it back on and performed the same exact steps with the same code and it worked!

Thanks for everyone who was helping out!

Answer (score 29):

I think you are not providing the `PORT NO.` required for `mongoDB`.

Please give the `port no.(27017)` along with localhost.

**Try this:**

```
var dbURI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/loc8r";
```

`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` means client was not able to connect to the given address. Please try with the above address.

I hope this helps.

Comment: it runs fine locally. the issue is when it tries to use the `MONGOLAB_URI`

Answer (score 15):

If you're getting this while running some replica sets in **Docker Compose** and trying to connect MongoDB Compass just make sure that you have the 'Direct connection' checked.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what "Direct connection" is doing?

Answer (score 7):

### if you use docker with this problem, I solve that with this solution

I have the same problem, other solutions not work for me but i did that with this way

> for mongo URI you must use your mongodb `service name` instead `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

for example in below docker-compose file my mongo service name is `mongodb-myapp` and i change uri like this `mongodb://mongodb-myapp:27017/myapp` and it works for me

```yaml
services:
  boilerplate-api-app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb-myapp:27017/myapp
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-myapp

 mongodb-myapp:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 6):

You just missed specifying the port number as shown:

```
  var dbURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/thenDBname"
```

Make sure to change localhost while hosting on production server.

Comment: Please review your answer. Both suggested lines are identical.

Answer (score 2):

The Heroku environment variable that gets created for an mLab add-on is called `MONGODB_URI` (`MONGOLAB_URI` may be a legacy thing).

Comment: I tried changing to `MONGODB_URI` but its still outputting the same error

Comment: What is `dbURI` set to when mongoose tries to connect? (obviously mask or change any sensitive info in the connection string - the format is what I'm interested in seeing).

Comment: Hmm I didn't think to check that... its coming in as `undefined`. This definitely has to be the issue, but looking at other people's setups I don't know why `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` isn't returning anything in the above code

Comment: Are you able to view the value via the Heroku CLI tool: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#getting-your-connection-uri ?

Comment: yes with that command I get something that looks like: mongodb://username:pasword@ds010000.mlab.com:10000/heroku_adcljdgt

Comment: Cool. And you're certain that the code is using `process.env.MONGODB_URI` and not `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` (which would be undefined)?

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct. I've seen this error (a lot) before as well. The 'undefined undefined' I believe is referring to your environment variables being undefined. Try console logging your environment variables to make sure they're valid.

Comment: so i console logged my environment and pushed it to heroku and it outputs 'production' which seems good. so I'm guessing the error is something to do with using `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` for some reason

Comment: Looking at the conversation below, pneumee is completely right about MONGOLAB_URI being legacy. I forgot about that, MONGODB_URI is what you'll want to use as your Heroku env variable.

However, for local testing, that shouldn't matter since you're just creating and providing a variable for yourself. 

Are you using Nodemon to start your application? What is the exact command you're using to start up?

For debugging, also try adding 
    console.log('DB URI: ' + process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
somewhere in this file just so you can easily spy on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, however, in my case I used different docker containers. Basically, the error is telling you that your application can not connect to the `monogodb` server. This can arise for instance by false port number, false IP address, etc. In my case the docker I had `mongodb` on was not in a same network as my server and so, the server couldn't fetch data from database.

To solve/debug it I done the followings:

1. Get the list of docker networks:

```
docker network ls
```

2. Inspect each network and find corresponding containers:

```
docker network inspect [Network Name]
```

3. Containers which must communicate with each other must be in a same network. So in my case I just disconnected server container from its network and reconnect it to the `mongodb`-network:

```
docker network disconnect [Network Name] [Container Name] 
docker network connect [Network Name] [Container Name]
```